# Use Firebase in iOS Automated Test

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, automated-tests

I have a project using Firebase via cocoapods in its early stages. The skeleton of the main app is in place and working with Firebase.

I am now trying to write an automated test for my service class which connects to Firebase. I am not getting any data when I run the unit test. I suspect it has something to do with accessing the Firebase config information, but Firebase spews out so many logs it is hard to tell.

I have added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to my test target.

Is there any trick to getting Firebase working with an automated test?